# How to read extended events through the .net code

Tags: .net, sql-server, xpath, extended-events

I had this requirement to log and read the extended events , I did achieve this through the Xpath queries and it worked as expected . Sometime has passed and now the .xel file has grown in size and the Xpath query takes long time to give back the results . I have heard there is .net code which will help to read the .xel file with more efficiency . Please help me the source code for the same .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extended Events data can be read programmatically using [QuerableXEventData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.xevent.linq.queryablexeventdata) from any .NET application, including PowerShell.

Below is a C# console example that extracts XE data from a trace that includes the `rpc_completed` event. The constructor overload here specifies the file pattern of the XE files to process. The project includes assembly references to `Microsoft.SqlServer.XE.Core` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq` (located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared\` on my system).

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq;

namespace ExtendedEventsExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xeFilePathPattern = @"C:\TraceFiles\rpc_completed*.xel";
            using (var events = new QueryableXEventData(xeFilePathPattern))
            {
                foreach (var xe in events)
                {
                    if (xe.Name == "rpc_completed")
                    {
                        var xeName = xe.Name;
                        var xeTimestamp = xe.Timestamp;
                        var xeStatementField = (String)xe.Fields["statement"].Value.ToString();
                        var xeDurationField = (UInt64)xe.Fields["duration"].Value;
                        var xeClientAppNameAction = (String)xe.Actions["client_app_name"].Value;
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            $"Name: {xeName}" +
                            $", Timestamp: {xeTimestamp}" +
                            $", Statement: {xeStatementField}" +
                            $", Duration: {xeDurationField}" +
                            $", ClientAppName: {xeClientAppNameAction}"
                            );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've found this method to be reasonably fast even with large trace files. You might consider using rollover files to limit trace file size. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801138/identifying-unused-procedures-using-sys-dm-exec-procedure-stats).